# What is the most natural ordering of basis 2-forms

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, differential-forms

When expanding 2-forms in $(\mathbb {R}^3 )^{\wedge 2}$ into a basis, you can use a cyclic trick to get the “most natural” basis set.

$\omega = a_{1,2} dx^1\wedge dx^2+ a_{2,3} dx^2 \wedge dx^3 + a_{3,1} dx^3\wedge dx^1$

What is the most natural combination for higher dimensions and higher grades?

Comment: There is nothing in particular to say in dimensions $>3$. In $\Bbb R^3$, I always use $23$, $31$, $12$ because then you get the correspondence (given by the Hodge star) with $1$-forms or the corresponding vector. (This is important when calculating the flux of a vector field by integrating a $2$-form.)

Comment: More generally, given an ordered basis of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\wedge k}$ we can always choose a corresponding ordered basis of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\wedge(n-k)}$. That said, It's not clear to me what makes a particular ordering more or less "natural" than another.